# frames routing in erb rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

Two questions.

Number 1:

This is how I am creating the frames in .erb files.

```
<frameset rows="170,*" frameborder="0" border="0" framespacing="0">
  <frame name="topNav" src="top_nav.html">
  </frame>
</frameset>
```

I have couple more frames inside above frameset. If I run this code, I get "No route matches [GET] "/top_nav.html". Question is: Is it really necessary to create/config routes of all the src locations specified in the frame tag?

Number 2:

In my application, I would need to change links in my app very frequently. If I need to consider the routing, I would need to create routes more frequently. Right? How can I avoid consider the routes? Basically, If I add any link in my app, it should work irrespective of fact that whether I have added the routes or not.

Comment: I have to ask, why are you using frames?

Comment: Need of the hour? :)

Comment: @kjmagic13 Actually, I already have html codes for webapp and I need to migrate it to rails with smallest code possible.

Comment: That's a shame, HTML5 considers frames to be obsolete: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html#frames

Answer (score 1):

You can put a static html page in your /publics folder, which will bypass rails routing and be served directly if e.g. someone visits `website.com/top_nav.html`, it'll serve up `public/top_nav.html`. The reason you're getting this error without visiting it is because the frame tries to load the src when you load the frame.

If you just want to serve a blank page as a catch-all for missing pages, you could create a controller that catches anything without another matching route, like so:

```
# config/rotues.rb
# make sure this is at the BOTTOM of your routes.rb
match "*path", to: "application#default", via: :all
```

And then in your application controller:

```
def default
  render nothing: true
end
```

This probably isn't the best way to handle it, though. You'd be best having the links you want created and served dynamically, but that'd depend on what your application is doing.

Comment: public folder? Where is public folder in rails app?

Btw, this does not answer my question. Question is : I want to create pages/links but do not want to create the routes. Possible?

Comment: Your rails project should have a folder called `public` in the root of the project folder. Any static files or folders placed here will be served through the server, without hitting the routes at all.